# Atom: Imitate 'Shift-Enter' keybinding of IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, atom-editor

In IntelliJ IDEA, one of the more helpful commands I've found is 'Shift-Enter' - it effectively moves the cursor to the end of the line, and starts a new line, thus not affecting the text on the current line.

I'd like to re-create this in Atom, but I can't seem to figure out how one would go about doing so. It doesn't look like you can have multiple editor actions for a given key combination, and I'm not sure if I simply can't find the esoteric editor command I'm looking for.

How can I recreate the behavior of shift-enter in IntelliJ for Atom?

Answer (score 1):

As it so happens, I stumbled across the shortcut: You can use `cmd-enter` to do the same action. I'm not sure what the underlying command is, but I hope this is helpful to other people!

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate this behaviour by adding this to your keymap:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'shift-enter': 'editor:newline-below'
```

Answer (score 0):

Detailed answer;

1. Freshly open atom editor
2. Open Keymap option
3. Copy this and paste this;
   'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
   'shift-enter': 'editor:newline-below'
4. Click save and close the file
   Press Shift and enter, Now you'll be able to form a new line below the line you currently in are regardless of the place you are typing in.